# Can't select anything on GRUB and it just boots to the first option, what could be the problem?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, radeon, bootloader

I'm using a USB keyboard but it wasn't like this right after I installed 12.04x64

One detail though: right after I installed the AMD Radeon drivers both the GRUB screen and Ubuntu's boot sequence looked different, specially the Ubuntu screen which now seems lowdef and stretched.

Update: uninstalling the drivers seemed to have fixed this, but now I don't know how it will affect the performance of my system.

Update 2: the problem is back, and now flash video stops after a few seconds (don't know if related but since it started at the same time...)

Comment: So, what driver are you using now? I find that my HD6770 card runs 15-20C cooler with the proprietary Catalyst driver (fglrx) than the open source radeon driver, so I try to use fglrx on all my installations. I am certainly having no problems with the one in the repository for 12.04.

Comment: try to hold on <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting

Comment: @Tim: thats the driver that was causing the problem, so I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some computers have problems with USB support before the operating system starts.
Does it work with a PS/2 keyboard (if you have a PS/2 port on your computer for that)?

Enabling legacy USB support in your BIOS if you have the option will usually fix this.